# Determine if two unsorted arrays are identical?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Given two **unsorted** arrays `A` and `B` with distinct elements, determine if `A` and `B` can be rearranged so that they are identical.

My strategy was as follows:

1. First, use a deterministic selection algorithm of **O(N)** time to find the **Max** of `A` and **Max** of `B`, if they don't have the same **Max**, we can automatically declare that they are **not** identical, otherwise, move to step 2.
2. Merge the two arrays together and create an array `C` of size **2N**.
3. Use the *counting sort algorithm* by creating an array `D` of size **Max(A)** and scanning `C` and bumping the counters of the appropriate index in `D` *(we don't actually need to complete the counting sort algorithm, we just need this intermediate step)*.
4. Scan the `D` array, if any `D[i] = 1`, we know that the arrays are not identical, otherwise they are identical.

**Claim:** Time Complexity O(N), and **no** constraints on space.

Is this a correct algorithm ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just iterate through and check whether each element of A matches the corresponding element of B?

Comment: @user2357112 I guess OP means if the arrays contain the same elements, not necessarily in the same order.

Comment: @user2357112 The two arrays are unsorted, we want to know if we can rearrange them in such a way that they are identical.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm The algo sounds correct, but not very practical because of it's memory usage. Besides, with non-int arrays, you have the problem how to map the elements to ints.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm: You asked how to tell whether they *are* identical, not if they can be *rearranged* to be identical. You should probably fix that.

Comment: What's the point of doing anything other than a linear scan to find the Max of an array? Creating the array C seems like an extravagant waste of memory when you can just iterate over A and then B.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I don't know, just the first thing I thought of but the idea is that it's still O(N)

Comment: You have to examine each element of the array, your first thought shouldn't be how to make it more complicated.

Comment: As stated, won't work. consider A = [1,3,3,7] B = [1,5,5,7] ... if the count incremented for one and decremented for the other, maybe. Others have pointed out the memory issue. ... How about scanning the final "count" array where the inputs are [1,9223372036854775805,9223372036854775807]; [1,9223372036854775806,9223372036854775807], it's really O(n+max(A)+max(B)) counting sort hides a bit of its time-complexity away in the constraint that all elements are elements of some constant-size finite set, and that constant-size manages to hide despite potentially being excessive.

Comment: If you can use counting sort, just use counting sort on both arrays, then compare the results.

Comment: If you do an XOR of each element of each array, it won't matter what the order is.

Comment: @dwoz Sigh. If you do an XOR of each element ... the result won't matter either, because there are infinite different arrays with the same xor value. Please, learn more about hashing before posting a load of nonsense (here and below)

Comment: @deviantfan, I understand hashes quite well.  Please keep this civil as well?  Doing an XOR convolution down the contents of each array would be very fast, and then comparing that product of each array, if the XOR hash was equal, it is still possible that the arrays are not equivalent...but if the XOR hash is different, there's no possible way that the arrays are equivalent.

Comment: @dwoz Yes. But it's still a fact that OP wants "same or not", not "probably same or not". And unlike eg. SHA2, getting collisions with a xor byte is very easy.

Comment: probability of collision would depend on how big the array elements are, no? If a too-small data element (say an 8 bit integer) was salted out to, say, a 48 bit word, then we definitely minimize collision, though as you say don't theoretically eliminate it.

Comment: @dwoz I'm not sure I understand what you mean. WIth 8 bit, you have 256 possible values. If you extend it to 48bit with some fixed data, it's still only 256 different values. If you extend it with something calculated from the original 8bit deterministically, it's still only 256 different values. If you extend with something random, you can't test for equality anymore.

Comment: pragmatically, seeds and salts can increase the entropy AND length of the resultant hash.  In the extant example, I'd imagine that using some combination of the array index and  chosen large random would do the trick.  You can test for equality as long as you apply the same salt to both arrays.  The salt can change, as long as you apply the same one to both sides.

Comment: also, pragmatically, we can both see that we're starting to wander afield of the question.  Let's engage another day on another question.

Comment: @dwoz `as long as you apply the same salt to both arrays` Which means, in the end, there are only 256 different values again and collisions have the same probability as before. `Let's engage another day on another question` Ok, bye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small correction (and the removal of a unnecessary step) ahead:

Find the max. elements of A and B. If not equal, quit.
Make an integer array C of size max(A) and set all elements to 0.
Iterate each element a of A and increment C[a].
Iterate each element b of B and decrement (!) C[b].
Check if C has at least one non-zero value; if yes then A and B have not the same elements.

Notes:
a) No need to make a merged array.
b) Incrementing for both arrays and checking
if the counter is 1 or 2 fails if some value occurs multiple times.
c) Incrementing for both arrays and checking if the counter is odd fails eg. if some
value is two times in A and 0 times in B. So 1x increment, 1x decrement, and checking for 0.

Now it works for integer arrays if the max. element is small enough that C can fit in the memory.

If there are large 64bit values in A and B, it won't work. If A and B are eg. double arrays, it won't work either. (You can convert the byte to int representations, but there will be large values again.)

If A and B are arrays of class objects, it won't work (generally). You would need a collision-free hash with hash values of max. eg. 4 byte so that numbers in this 4 byte are possible array sizes, and depending on the class, such hash functions may not be possible.

Comment: One could use a hash map instead of the counter array to overcome some of the restrictions.

Comment: @Henry If I had to suggest something sane, I would just sort both arrays from the beginning and compare them then :) Yes, a hash map helps for the current approach, but all I did is correcting OPs algo so it works correctly, without changing too much.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic way to solve this task is to add elements of the first array to hashtable. Then iterate the second array and check if each element is present in the hash table.

Hash table has amortized insert and search time O(1) (when using sufficiently good hash), so overall algorithm will run in O(N) time and consume O(N) additional space.

This approach works for all element types (not just small ints, as required by counting sort). However, if your elements are small ints, you can replace hashtable with plain boolean array.

Also if elements of arrays are not distinct, this algorithm can be modified by storing counters as values in hash table.

Comment: A hashtable object lookup is about the most EXPENSIVE way I can imagine to do this.

Comment: This only works if there are no repeats. For a general solution, you need a hash table of counts.  Increment them with the first array. Decrement and remove at zero for the second. Then verify the table is empty.

Comment: @Gene Aivean said already that it has to be modified to work with non-distinct elements

Answer (score -5):

O(n) component of the question means that we're answering someone's homework question.  Nobody cares about this in real world computing (mostly).

Why not first look at Array[].length() to see if they're identical?

Then, write a hash function that results in the same value regardless of order. (i.e. do an XOR of each/all items).  In MOST computing languages the results of comparing a hash should be consistent with equals.

Comment: Hash function will not guarantee equality. Also, comparing two arrays is very common task in real world. One example is to assert results of method call in unit test. However, in real world there are built-in tools to achieve this, like HashSets.

Comment: `O(n) component of the question means that we're answering someone's homework question. Nobody cares about this in real world computing (mostly).` I actually cared with a 400GB array last week that had nothing to do with homework.

Comment: constructing hashsets of arrays?  oy!  so much overhead!  yes, it works...so does setting up 500 old women in malaysia to each call out a value over the phone.

Comment: ...and your edit is plain nonsense. a) Hash algos are distinct from programming languages. b) A hash algo, per definition, generates hashes, and hashes are not collision-free. It's not the same as equals.

Comment: @dwoz, probably I would regret writing this, but: 1. I didn't downvote you, but I will now. 2. sorting has O(NlogN) time for arbitrary data, while constructing hashtable is O(N). 3. Calculating hash to verify equality is good **approximate** approach. But clearly it's not 100% reliable.

Comment: @Aivean:  I would simply not imagine going to a hashtable.  Constructing it may be O(n) but CONSTRUCTING AND READING is not.

Comment: @dwoz, actually it is.

Comment: The "field" of programming something outside of school? Yes. And I promise you it does matter to the boss if some program runs one hour or hundred years. Not everything is Facebook, Iphone apps and stuff like that. (and even Facebook needs performant background software). Complexity *does* matter.

Comment: @dwoz no point to argue with you further. Please [read the manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and then come back.